# How to convert array to key-values

Tags: javascript, arrays, key, key-value, key-pair

I have the following array:

```
{
  "red": "Red",
  "blue": "Blue"
}
```

And I want to convert it to a key-value pair like this:

```
[
{"id":"red", "value":"Red"},
{"id":"blue","value":"Blue"}
]
```

Comment: Please update your answer with what you have tried. See => https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That's not an array you start out with; it's an array you end up with

Comment: NOTE: All three answers below worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const obj = {
  red: "Red",
  blue: "Blue",
};

const result = Object.entries(obj).map((o) => {
  const [prop, val] = o;
  return {
    id: prop,
    value: val
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Glad I could help...

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the key-value pairs to entries and map their key (`id`) and `value` to objects.

```js
const colors = {
  "red": "Red",
  "blue": "Blue"
};

const values = Object.entries(colors).map(([id, value]) => ({ id, value }));

console.log(values);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the object's [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) that to the desired output format.

```js
const obj = {
  "red": "Red",
  "blue": "Blue"
}

const result = Object.entries(obj)
  .map(([id, value]) => ({ id, value }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You're wlecome! I realize you're new to SO, so a little suggestion: Please consider upvoting answers that worked for you :D

Comment: Good point! Thanks